# What type of exception is a urllib3 connection failure?

Tags: python, flask, python-requests

I have a section of code that gives me a urllib3 error when the IP address of the host it's connecting to is wrong, and also stops the App from starting up.

This connection attempt is in a view(not the main view), which I'm assuming is being called when the application starts up.

I want to write a `try` to check for this exception, however, the error doesn't mention what exception type it's seeing.

**Q:** What Exception type can I specify in the `try` to handle this error when then application starts up?

**Error**

> Was unable to import app
>   Error: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='10.0.0.1', port=834): Max retries exceeded with url: /items (Caused by NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 113] No route to host',))

Thanks in advance.

Comment: But it does mention it. `from urllib3.exceptions import NewConnectionError`

Comment: When I set `except NewConnectionError:` I see in my lint that it's not a recognized variable.

Comment: You need to actually import it

Comment: Cool, sorted thanks. I had to `from requests.exceptions import ConnectionError` and then specify the `try` with and exception `ConnectionError`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks @cricket_007

solved it by importing the exceptions for requests.

```
from requests.exceptions import ConnectionError
```

and then trigger in the `try` statement.

```
try:
    <<something>>
except ConnectionError:
    <<something>>
```

Answer (score 0):

In answer to the question actually asked, you can find out the base class(es) of a Python class via its `__bases__` tuple. For example,

```
>>> class MyZeroDivide( ZeroDivisionError):
...   pass
>>> z = MyZeroDivide()  # instance
>>> z.__class__        
<class '__main__.MyZeroDivide'>  # class
>>> z.__class__.__bases__
(<type 'exceptions.ZeroDivisionError'>,)  # base class(es)
>>> z.__class__.__bases__[0].__bases__
(<type 'exceptions.ArithmeticError'>,)    # up a level
>>> z.__class__.__bases__[0].__bases__[0].__bases__
(<type 'exceptions.StandardError'>,)      # up two levels
```